# Spring Tomcat : Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements . Saw '301 Moved Permanently'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hazelcast

I am trying to bring up a tomcat server, and am facing problems with loading definitions of spring beans. The `applicationContext.xml` reads as follows :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr" xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring META-INF/hazelcast-spring-2.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd


    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd">
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
```

The IDE (Idea) says it is unable to resolve the file `hazelcast-spring-2.0.xsd`

The error log says:

```
13:19:59,909 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
13:20:02,964 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.0.xsd; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 35; s4s-elt-character: 
**Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.**
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I did not touch this file.

Comment: Why have you added `**` ? It's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: That is just for higlighting. Will remove it as it may caause confusion

Comment: try to set absolute path to this file instead relative ( as a first test if there is something wrong with path or file itself )

Comment: @LearningToDesign Did you ever solve this?  I have the exact same problem?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The problem was that the hazelcast schema version mentioned in the applicationContext.xml "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring META-INF/hazelcast-spring-2.0.xsd" was different than the actual jar I was using, I think mine was 2.4 , so changing it to "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring META-INF/hazelcast-spring-2.4.xsd" solved the problem. 
The explanation is that spring is first searching the xsds in the jars and then on internet. So because of the wrong version it was not finding it in the jar, but was hitting the internet.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem for http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.5.xsd and solved it by adding hazelcast-all with version 3.5 in the maven dependencies rather than simply hazelcast.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```